# add firebase-crashlytics to my android projects failed

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

**this is my project/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '4.0.1'
    }
    repositories {

        google()  
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {

        google()  
    }
}
```

**this is my app/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
    ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nd.eoht"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

AS report 2 errors:

1: Task failed with an exception.

-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'play-services-ads-identifier.properties'.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.actions.ItemListIntents found in modules jetified-google_basement-runtime.jar (:google_basement:) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)

......